# Call a Method From Inside dom-repeat in Polymer

Tags: dom, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-1.x

I'm having this situation where I need to call a method from the dom-repeat. Below is my code

```
<template is='dom-repeat' items="[[_dataArray]]" as="rowItem">
     <template is='dom-repeat' items="[[_objectArray]]" as="columnItem">
         <template>
             <span>[[_getColumnItemValue(rowItem, columnItem)]]</span>
         </template>
     </template>
</template>
```

and in my `_getColumnItemValue` method, I want to get the value for an object with key specified by the `columnData` attribute.

Like `rowData[columnData]`

```
_getColumnItemValue: function(rowData, columnData) {
    return rowData[columnData];
}
```

My problem is the method `_getColumnItemValue` is not being called. Is there any better way to do achieve this?

Comment: My arrays will look something like: 

`_dataArray = [
  {
    "XValue": 0,
    "WaferYAxis": 1.353912,
    "WaferXAxis": -0.779266,
    "EndEffector": 0.035248
  },
  {
    "XValue": 7.370312,
    "WaferYAxis": 1.198273,
    "WaferXAxis": -0.601959,
    "EndEffector": 0.011902
  },
  {
    "XValue": 14.578125,
    "WaferYAxis": 0.987854,
    "WaferXAxis": -0.476074,
    "EndEffector": 0.004578
  }]
and _objectArray=['EndEffector', 'WaferXAxis', 'WaferYAxis' ]`.

This object array can be different in each case. and are provided as attributes.

Comment: vishnu !! did you solve this issue??

Comment: I Couldnt sove that issue in this case. But i have managed to the exact same thing in one of my other projects. The only difference is that, my _objectArray is not an array of strings, its an array of objects. and instead of one way data binding, i used two way (Dont know if it has any relevance in this case). I will post the code below.

Comment: vishnu have a look at this problem ,I'm stuck here,it also looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184556/property-change-not-reflecting-in-ui-when-its-set-from-dom-repeats-function-p

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly as you pasted, then you have one too many `<template>` tags.

```
<template is='dom-repeat'>
  <template is='dom-repeat'>
     <span></span>
  </template>
</template>
```

The innermost template must be removed. You are rendering that instead of the `<span>`.

Comment: Oh. That <template> tag is not actually there. I was trying some things. Thank you for notifying

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what the problem is then. Could you add more code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to make this thing working. Not exactly in this case, but in another project, with exact same logic. The only change was my _objectArray was not an array of strings, it was an array of objects. So the code will look like this:

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tableData}}" as="rowData">
                        <tr>
                            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{headers}}" as="columnData">
                                <td>
                                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkType(columnData, 'check')}}">
                                        <paper-checkbox disabled="{{getAttributeValue(columnData, 'disabled')}}" checked="{{getRowData(rowData, columnData)}}" on-change="checkBoxSelected"></paper-checkbox>
                                    </template>
                                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkType(columnData, 'led')}}">
                                        <led-indicator on="{{!getRowData(rowData, columnData)}}"></led-indicator>
                                        <span style="display: none;">{{getRowData(rowData, columnData)}}</span>
                                    </template>
                                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkType(columnData, 'link')}}">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" on-click="tableRowClicked">{{getRowData(rowData, columnData)}}</a>
                                    </template>
                                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkType(columnData, 'text')}}">
                                        <span>{{getRowData(rowData, columnData)}}</span>
                                    </template>
                                </td>
                            </template>
                        </tr>
                    </template>`

See the method `getRowData`

`getRowData: function (row, column) {
            return row[column.key];
        },`
and

`checkType: function (columnData, type) {
            var isType = false;
            isType = columnData.type.toLowerCase() == type.toLowerCase();
            return isType;
        },`

This is for a table, which can dynamically add or remove rows and columns and show different type of elements like, a text, link, checkbox some of my custom controls like led-indicator etc.

The logic behind is, the headers array will be used to generate the table columns, this array contains objects of structure

`{
                    name: 'Popular Name',
                    key: 'PopularName',
                    type: 'text'
                }`

and table data contains array of object, which contains the key specified in the headers array.
Hope this may be useful for some one.