# Property change not reflecting in UI when its set from dom-repeat's function - Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-1.x, dom-repeat

I have array of objects and a property, my dom-repeat structure is like as below

```
     <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{arrayOfObj}}">              //first dom repeat      
       <span>[[myProperty]]<span> //here also its not updating      
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[_checkSomeCondition()]]">    //calling method from dom-if
          <span>[[myProperty]]<span>     //here its not getting updated value
        </template>
     </template>
```

I have a property

```
 properties:{
 myProperty:{
  type:Boolean
 }
}
```

my function is called each time when dom-repeat iterates

```
 _checkSomeCondition:function() {  //I'll check and set property
  if(some condition){
     this.myProperty = true;
     return true;
   }
   else{
     this.myProperty = false;
     return true;
   }
 console.log(this.myProperty); //I'll get the updated value on console
}
```

but its not changing in screen!! It will display whatever data it set first time  inside _checkSomeCondition !! but in console its updating

For testing I inserted a button and after all dom-repeat rendered on tapping that button I called some function ,there when I changed value it get reflected everywhere

```
    this.myProperty = true;
```

but why its not working when value is changed inside a function which is called by dom-repeat?? I tried all 3 ways of updating a object

Plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/iAStve97dTTD9cv6iygX?p=preview

Comment: I feel like a filter function really has no business updating a value like you are doing.  Why wouldn't you just dynamically set the value on the object via another method?

Comment: actually this is demo code so I'm returning true in both if and else statement ,but in my original code I must do some more validations! but syntax remains almost same..

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable via this.myValue = 'somevalue'; won't update binding.

Its best to set variables via `this.set('variablename', 'variablevalue');`

You could also, after setting a property via `this.variablename = 'variablevalue'; this.notifyPath('variablename'`);

Comment: Hey thanx for the reply !! I tried your solution but still have same issue! Please check updated plunker

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_checkSomeCondition(myProperty)]]">    //calling method from dom-if
    <span>[[myProperty]]<span>   //here its not getting updated value
</template>
```

And then

```
_checkSomeCondition: function(property) {
```

Comment: I don't know will it works or not!! but still if  I wanted to update many property, I can't send all those from function call, this method is not feasible!!

Comment: Have a look at this Plunk as an example of how you can use reactive variables in Polymer. I have included examples of modifying a variable in an array and calculating using a variable external to the array. You may just need to rethink what you are trying to achieve. https://plnkr.co/edit/LYqWbGOOBeiq6Perjvzb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code like below. Im not sure if it helps for your senario. Please have a look may help to bring up ideas

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sensor.Sensor.Contaminants}}" index-as="index">
    <span>{{myProperty}}<span> //here also its not updating

    <div>{{_checkSomeCondition(index)}}<div>     //here its not getting updated value
</template>`

And your `_checkSomeCondition` method will be:

`_checkSomeCondition: function() {  //I'll check and set property
            console.log(index);
            if(<your condition>){
                this.myProperty = 'true';
            } else{
                this.myProperty = 'false';
            }
            // Return whatever you want to show in UI
            return this.myProperty;
            console.log(this.myProperty); //I'll get the updated value on console
        },`

and your myProperty should notify the changes. So the property should have `notify: true`.

With this code i could see the changes in the UI as expected. Let me know if it helps